# Create - How to handle empty response

Tags: react-admin

My API doesn't return any response in body on POST,PATCH, etc for some resources.
How are we supposed to handle this case in data provider ?
I tried to return an empty data object but unfortunately I get the error :
"The response to 'CREATE' must be like { data: ... }, but the received response does not have a 'data' key. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'CREATE'."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your dataProvider looks like or what the response of your API for POST/PUT requests is, but the problem is probably located in your dataProvider's `convertHTTPResponseToREST` as this is responsible for handling your API's responses.
Try the following:
`case CREATE:
  return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };`

If this doesn't work either, then try this one:

`case CREATE:
  return { data: json };`

Comment: The response coming from the api is empty meaning that there is no json so consequently no ID.

Comment: Yes, it does not work as I haven't any id from the API. Using a fake id and params.data did the trick